# htaccess Redirect & Rewrite Conditions

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get my website to redirect a couple of pages to a new 'error page' that I've created. Can I get y'all to take a look? An already created .htaccess file was done for me, so that I would stay away from www.'s and go with example.com only. So, take a look and tell me what's up? Please :)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RedirectPermanent 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/missing-page.html

RedirectPermanent 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/missing-page.html

RedirectPermanent 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/missing-page.html

RedirectPermanent 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/missing-page.html

RedirectPermanent 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html
```

Comment: My apologies - in attempting to simplify the problem, I should've first made note of the multiple RedirectPermanents being used for several oldpage.html files... That is, there are multiple old pages, which will all be going to a missing-page.html

Comment: I'd like /oldpage.html to redirect to missing-page.html in the same folder

Comment: I'm getting 404 errors for all of the pages I've specified to be redirected.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Trying that now! Thank you!

Comment: After trying: example.com/.htaccess     I was taken to a 403 Forbidden page.

Comment: OK - trying that now.

Comment: No problems accessing it. From multiple browsers & devices.

Comment: If you're not getting 500 even with some junk text in .htaccess that means your htaccess is not enabled

Comment: Thanks, anubhava - I'll go and figure out how to enable it now! Thanks again :)

Comment: By the way, your `RedirectPermanent 301` syntex is wrong. it should either be `RedirectPermanent` or `Redirect 301`

Comment: THAT WAS THE TRICK! :) THANKS STARKEEN

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks - and, to anub for giving me some great troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

‘RedirectPermanent 301 …’ is invalid. The RedirectPermanent determines the redirect is a 301 redirect, therefore you do not pass the status code. Simply use ‘RedirectPermanent /old…’.